# Physical Punishment in Schools/College

Tags: education, punishment

A sports teacher slapped my friend twice in the face in front of the class for not attending the sports class.

Should this be allowed? Tomorrow we are going to be on a strike so what points and facts in the light of law I should put on the table.

Comment: What grade?  What country?  What type of school?

Comment: 12th grade, private school, Pakistan

Answer (score 1):

The school-teacher-student relationship has historically often been given some of the same privileges and legal exemptions that are granted to the family-parent-child relationship, corporal punishment among them.

All I can find on Pakistani law [suggests corporal punishment is legal but discouraged](http://www.corpun.com/rules2.htm#pakistan):

> At federal level, corporal punishment is lawful in schools under
>   Article 89 of the Penal Code. Ministerial directives in the different
>   provinces have instructed teachers not to use it, in some cases even
>   in private schools ... but these are clearly not enforced in practice.

Answer (score -1):

Corporal Punishment is what that is called.  My edited answer is that you should tell adults/parents what happened and leave it with them.

Show support privately to your friend who was slapped.  There are other battles out there to fight.  Do not get involved unless you are asked to by your parents or the school.